# “Virtue is its own reward”

Tags: traduction, anglais, proverbes

Est-ce qu'il y a un équivalent en français qui rend aussi bien ?

J'ai trouvé des exemples [en latin](http://www.4crests.com/lisofcommot.html), donc cette expression doit avoir un certain pédigrée.

Comment: Il me semble que l'idiome est _Virtue is its own reward_

Comment: @rds, c'est effectivement la traduction du latin sur la page citée. Je ne sais pas pourquoi j'avais goodness en tête.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Il me semble que l'expression est *Virtue is its own reward*.

- [Poetic amusement,: consisting of a sample of sonnets, epistolary poems ...](http://books.google.com/books?id=j1xDAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA121&dq=virtue%20is%20its%20own%20reward&hl=fr&ei=RrrgToCeFoGG8gOV4Iz8BA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=2&ved=0CDQQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=virtue%20is%20its%20own%20reward&f=false) de Rev. Thomas Beck

> Tis said that "Virtue is its own reward"
>   
>   On trouve évidemment des dérivés

- [The bravery award institue](http://archive.gg.ca/media/doc.asp?lang=e&DocID=31)

> It is true that bravery, like virtue, is its own reward.
>   
>   traduit par

- [Remise de décorations pour actes de bravoure](http://archive.gg.ca/media/doc.asp?lang=f&DocID=31)

> Il est vrai que la bravoure, comme la vertu, trouve sa récompense en elle-même
>   
>   Edit: J'ai trouvé dans

- Dictionnaire de l'Académie française, 4th Edition (1762) (à [récompense](http://artflx.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/dicos/pubdico1look.pl?strippedhw=r%C3%A9compense)):

> La vertu est elle-même sa récompense

Et dans le trésor (proverbes de "récompense"):

- (Bonald, Essai analyt., 1800, p. 23)

> La vertu porte avec elle sa récompense et le crime son châtiment

Vous pouvez donc traduire le titre du roman de Jerry Allen McCuien  par *Bonté trouve sa récompense en elle-même* ou *La bonté est elle-même sa récompense*.

Comment: Je trouve que « La vertu trouve sa récompense en elle-même » sonne déjà mieux que « Vertu est sa propre récompense »

Comment: @Benjol En effet, Google translate n'est pas la meilleure source littéraire. Et j'ai finalement trouvé des références dans le Dictionnaire de l'Académie et dans le Trésor de la langu frnaçaise

Answer (score 5):

Une citation de [Sénèque](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%A9n%C3%A8que) est assez proche :

> La récompense d'une bonne action, c'est de l'avoir accomplie.

C'est peut-être la traduction française de l'exemple en latin que vous avez croisé lors de vos recherches.